# Problem-Based formulation in MatLab: Sets and Subsets

Tags: matlab, gams-math

I am an GAMS user how has to go over to MatLab due to company policies.
I have written a model in GAMS that I am now wrtining in Matlab. I am using the problem based approuch.

The question I have is about sets and subsets

For example in GAMS

```
sets
         NodeIndex                               Nodes of the system                     /1*3/
         GenIndex(NodeIndex)                     Generator Index                         /1/
         NoGenIndex(NodeIndex)                   Nodes with no generation

NoGenIndex(NodeIndex) = not GenIndex(NodeIndex)
```

As seen,  GenIndex(NodeIndex) and  NoGenIndex(NodeIndex) are a subset of NodeIndex
Example of an optimization variable:

```
PG(NodeIndex) Generated active power
Theta0(GenIndex)
```

Then when I bound the problem, I can say that certain sets should have zero generation.

```
PG.fx(NoGenIndex) = 0;
```

However, when reading the instructions in MatLab for problembased I can't find something similar. Is possible to define subsets in Matlab problem-based formulation?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can index into OptimizationVariables or OptimizationExpressions using either numeric index vectors or string. See for example:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimvar.html#mw_9da91e17-8359-4deb-9b42-b08b64a3646b